# python subclasses have general functions shared across them

Tags: python

I've created a base class and a subclass. I'll be creating more subclasses, however I have some general functions that will be used across all subclasses. Is this the proper way of setting it up? I'm assuming it would be easier to add the def to the base class and then call it within each subclass. Is that possible to do or recommended?

```
""" 
Base class for all main class objects 
"""
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, attributes, children):
        self.name = name
        self.attributes = attributes if attributes is not None else {}
        self.children = children if children is not None else []

"""
contains the settings for cameras
"""
class Camera(Node):
    def __init__(self, name="", attributes=None, children=None, enabled=True):
        super(Camera, self).__init__(name=name, attributes=attributes, children=children)
        self.enabled = enabled

        # defaults
        add_node_attributes( nodeObject=self)


# General class related functions
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
""" Adds attributes to the supplied nodeObject """
def add_node_attributes(nodeObject=None):

    if nodeObject:
        nodeObject.attributes.update( { "test" : 5 } )


# create test object
Camera()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the general methods on the base class and call them from the subclass:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, attributes, children):
        self.name = name
        self.attributes = attributes if attributes is not None else {}
        self.children = children if children is not None else []
    def add_node_attributes(self):
        self.attributes.update( { "test" : 5 } )
```

This allows you to take maximum advantage of inheritance. Your subclasses will have the method `add_node_attributes` available to them:

```
c=Camera()
c.add_node_attributes()
```

You can also call it from within the child class:

```
class Camera(Node):
    def __init__(self, name="", attributes=None, children=None, enabled=True):
        super(Camera, self).__init__(name=name, attributes=attributes, children=children)
        self.enabled = enabled

        # defaults
        self.add_node_attributes()
```

Comment: how do i then call the function from the subclass Camera?

Comment: what about within the Camera? def__init__

Comment: i will once im allowed to. i have to wait 5 minutes SO requires sadly.